# Error borrar elemento de array typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Buenas estoy intentando borrar un `element` del array que tengo con el splice pero me esta petando y no se porque.

no es una array de objetos asique me deberia de dejar

```
borrarTurno(turno:string){
    let index= 0;
    for (let turnoABorrar of this.datosTurnos) {
       if (turnoABorrar.turno == turno){
          this.datosTurnos[index].splice(index,1);    
       }
       index++;
    }
  }
```

Este es el método que tengo en el .ts y en el navegador me peta

> AjustesComponent.html:93 ERROR TypeError: turnoABorrar.splice is not a
>   function
>       at

...

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta e incluir el contenido de `datosTurnos`. Al saber la estructura de tus datos es más fácil entender que es lo que va mál

Comment: this.datosTurnos.splice(index,1); me funciono asi

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto :

```
borrarTurno(turno:string){
  datosTurnos.splice(datosTurnos.indexOf(dato => dato.turno === turno), 1);
}
```

Comment: Buenas Fernando, gracias por responder. Pero en vez de decir "prueba esto" es mejor explicar el funcionamiento del codigo. Si no, el usuario que vaya a utilizarlo solo puede copiar y pegar sin llegar a entender cómo modificarlo para adaptarlo a otros requisitos. Un saludo

Comment: Fernando, para complementar lo ya dicho antes, por favor lee [answer].

Comment: [Posiblemente te han votado negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)

Comment: Agrega más información sin embargo creo que tu respuesta es la correcta